# Z-index does not work in ie

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have multiple divs in my webpage. there is this javascript slide show and i have put a menu over that slideshow and positioned the div absolute. I have formatted the order with z-indexes. They work perfect in firefox but Internet Explorer does not work on that. what can be the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code or my answer is `purple`.

Comment: dows z-index work in ie exactly the way it works in firefox?

Comment: The z-index property is supported in all major browsers. Might be worth going over the basics just quickly: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I remember IE7 having this caveat: if you declare a z-index on something, you have to explicitly put a (lower, of course) z-index on its parent container, otherwise it might cause issues. IE8 seems to handle the thing pretty well, of what version are you talking about?

Comment: My guess is we're talking about **IE6**, urgh… Getting some chills over here.

Comment: IE has a bug that if you set the lowest z-index to 0, it won't work as expected. Always start with 1+. Children will inherit parent's z-indexes.

Comment: Follow instruction described in this article: http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a full page wrapper div anywhere or can make one **or** there is an ancestor/parent div you can freely alter,...

Explicitly state `position: relative;` ***or*** `position: absolute;` and either way also set `z-index: 0;` or the lowest value you can use.

Also some browsers (especially some IEs) allow a smaller range of z-index.

For sure values between 1 and 100 are safe. Probably more like 1-255 but I vaguely recall some old issue,...

Comment: IE sometimes bugs over `z-index: 0;` Always start from 1.

Comment: @Trip No problem, when browsers render CSS, sometimes it helps for the rendering engine to have a base element with a very well defined position and size (especially width.)