# How to show Div on top of its parent div?

Tags: html

I am trying to show a hidden Div on click event using JS. This Div contains UL which sometimes happens to be of height more than the parent Div. In such cases, parent Div scroll appears.

What I want is to show this list inside a child Div, on top of parent Div. This way the height of list will not affect the UI of page.

Here's the image of what's happening :
[image]

Note: Blue border represents the parent Div & list with grey background is inside a child Div.

And I have already tried applying `position:relative;z-index:9999;`

Comment: can you share the complete code? position:relative will keep the positioning relative to parent.

Comment: Position relative will position it "relative" to it's parent container.

Comment: thanks guys! sorry for late reply. You mean parent's style (position) does matter when using z-index? I am a little less with css :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to give the parent a zindex (lower) too.  See [Z-index does not work in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087553/z-index-does-not-work-in-ie) fir more ideas.

Comment: thanks! I tried to set parent's z-index to 1 and child's to 9. Also changed the position of child to relative. But there's is no change I can see. And I am sure there's no style other than this is applied to it.

Comment: Grasping at straws - but, make sure all the elements that make up the items displaying / hidden has a z-order.